# Distribution of ratio of sums of gamma distributions

Tags: probability-distributions

If $X_1,X_2$ are independent r.v.s with $X_1 \sim \Gamma(\alpha,\theta)$, $X_2 \sim \Gamma(\beta,\theta)$ then it is known that
$$\frac{X_1}{X_1+X_2} \sim \text{Beta}(\alpha,\beta)$$
Let $X_i$ be iid with $X_i \sim \Gamma(\alpha,\theta)$.
What is the distribution of
$$\frac{X_1}{\sum_{i=1}^n X_i}$$
?
What about the special case where $\alpha=2$, $\theta=1$?

EDIT: Matched question to did's answer :)

Comment: Hint: $X_2+\cdots+X_n$ is $\Gamma((n-1)\alpha,\theta)$. (Hence the special case is Beta$(2,2n-2)$.)

Comment: Didier, that's an answer, not a hint!

Comment: @DilipSarwate I obeyed your command. :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This follows from the $n=2$ case since the distribution of $X_2+\cdots+X_n$ is $\Gamma((n-1)\alpha,\theta)$. (Hence the special case is Beta$(2,2n-2)$.) Note that none of this depends on $\theta$, as long as  this parameter stays the same for every $X_k$.